# One last issue getting DeepChem running with TensorFlow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I'm trying to install the DeepChem multi objective deep learning code on a MacBook Pro with a Python 2.7 environment.  I did a manual install of DeepChem and its required components and all seemed to go well, no errors. When I tried to run the test data I got an error "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime". I then installed TensorFlow again in the VirtualEnv Python environment and this again went well. The Tensorflow validation worked OK.  I tried the DeepChem test examples again and got the same error "Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime". Can anyone please suggest a solution? Should I provide a complete error path?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is really general and this is not really a tensorflow problem so much as a virtualenv/dependency question.

That said here are some possible fixes:

- are you sure you have activated the virtualenv (should show
  environment in parentheses before the bash prompt)?  If not use:
  `source activate ENV_NAME`
- if you are running from an IDE (like pycharm) are you sure you are
  using the virtualenv as your interpreter?  If not follow this
  [guide](http://exponential.io/blog/2015/02/10/configure-pycharm-to-use-virtualenv/).

Again, more information about your use case would be very helpful.

Comment: Yes I think I had virtualenv running although I only got (tensor flow) before the bash promo. Thanks for your help, I will try both things.